# PrimeNG Element not scoped, can't be styled with default Angular 2 ViewEncapsulation (Emulated)

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm trying to use the `styleUrls` property when declaring my Angular 2 component to take advantage of [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#view-encapsulation) but there seems to be a problem when elements get inserted into the DOM after Angular has its completed initialization.

My situation is with a [PrimeNG paginator](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/paginator) that I currently can't style since it doesn't get applied a scope by Angular.

See below the `<p-datatable>` element has a scope (it existed in the original markup) but `<p-paginator>` does not (was added to DOM after the fact).

[image]

Therefore the style inserted by Angular into `HEAD` does not match my elements:

```
<style>
    p-datatable[_ngcontent-xnm-4] p-paginator[_ngcontent-xnm-4]:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Is this a limitation of view encapsulation in Angular 2 or is there a way to have it "re-scope" the DOM on demand?

*edited for typo and clarified title*

Comment: I was facing [the same issue with ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/984), and the Angular UI team proposed the same solution, using ``:host \deep\``. So I guess Angular does not provide a way to scope dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As you noticed this is because of the [Shadow DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom) and the style scoping it provides. Your template only contains the the `p-datatable` which correctly gets scoped, but its child elements that are added after the fact are NOT scoped. In order to apply your custom styling you can choose two approaches.

### Solution 1 - Special Selectors (Recommended)

I personally recommend this as you can still maintain view encapsulation (Shadow DOM). We can still target our component level templates that use [PrimeNG](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/) by using the `:host` and `/deep/` [selectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors) as such

```
:host /deep/ .ui-paginator-bottom {
  display: none;
}
```

What this does is force a style down through the child component tree into all the child component views so even though the `p-datatable` is the only tag present in your component's own template, the style will still be applied as it is a child to the component in the DOM.

### Solution 2 - Disable View Encapsulation

At the component level you can disable the [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#view-encapsulation) by setting it to *ViewEncapsulation.None* as such

```
...
import { ..., ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component {
...
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
}
```

Comment: If only I could upvote it 10 times. This answer is perfect and I couldn't find this info anywhere in their documentation or the forum. Thank you!

Comment: I 100% agree with reflog. Was hunting for this solution for the past 3 hours. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer! This helped me big times!

Comment: Wow, I literally have never seen either the ":host" or "/deep" deep selectors...ever.

Comment: Just for future reference: note that `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` implies that any scoping for `@import` is ignored too. So, even scoping with some `.non-existing` in `.non-existing { @import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap'; }` has no effect; the imported CSS simply applies to the full page. (Likewise, some `.existing { @import '...'; }` might seem to work, but actually ignores the `.existing` too.) In other words, when using Angular CLI 6, one might just add the styles to `angular.json` instead.

Comment: The solution with special selectors is exactly what I was looking for but on the official documentation it's indicated as deprecated: `The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated`. Will we only have the second solution in the future or are there other solutions replacing the first one ?

Comment: If somebody tries to do the same with angular 13/14(probably some previous versions too), `/deep/` won't work, you have to use their `::ng-deep` instead